# When does a battery self-discharge?

Tags: lead-acid

I want to measure lead acid battery self-discharge but I not sure when to trigger the self-discharge measurement algorithm. Is it constantly self-discharge or only in standby mode (no load)? If a battery does always self-discharge then what is the self-discharge rates for load-discharging and charging conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Battery self-discharge is caused by:

- leakage current flowing internally INSIDE the battery, you cannot measure it !
- chemical processes inside the battery causing loss of the amount of energy stored in the battery

A way to measure this could be to:

- fully charge the battery
- disconnect from charger
- wait until the battery voltage has reached it's lowest value (when the battery is empty), note that could take a YEAR (on a lead-acid battery) !

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do know the fact battery self-discharging occurs internally. My algorithm is basically a rate counter which changes counting rate according to temperature (initial rate provided by battery manufacturer). The problem is, I don't know when to start that counter. It seems the best starting point is when the battery is fully charged or is in standby mode.

Comment: From you question it appeared to me as if you thought that self-discharge is like a "state" that the battery gets in to and out of (when used). When to start your counter, I don't see what the problem is. Just start it when the battery is idle (not charging or being loaded). Do you use the counter as a timer ? Then measure the idle time of the battery.

Comment: Batteries self-discharge when they are not fully discharged. In other words, pretty much all the time. You should start your algorithm any time the true state of charge is known. Practically speaking, this will probably be only when the battery is fully charged.